# std::remove_if with lambda predicate

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I would like to remove an object from a vector based on a lambda predicate:

```
class tmr
{
public:
  tmr();
  ~tmr();
  static void start();
  bool is_time_out(double sec);
  double t_elapsed();
};

struct sobj
{
  int count;
  bool tflag;
  int ID;
  tmr timer;
  friend bool is_stime(timer& objtimer,double sec)
   {
    return objtimer.is_time_out(sec);
   }
};
```

somewhere in the main program, I populate a `vector<sobj>`, then after some time, I want to remove the element whose ID is specified and whose timer has elapsed.

I did this , and it complains about not being able to convert void to bool

```
sobj strobj;
vector<sobj> vecobj;

vecobj.erase(std::remove_if(vecobj.begin(),vecobj.end(),[&](const sobj& mysobj){return ( mysobj.ID== THE_ID && mysobj.is_stime(mysobj.timer,5));}),vecobj.end());
```

Comment: Could you show your compiler, its version, and paste the actual error?

Comment: @Useless: The unhelpful part is that Sam didn't include this part of the error: `foo.cc:11:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'is_sobj'`

Comment: Can you post the actual error message, instead of your interpretation of it?  highlight, copy, paste into text editor, add 4 spaces at front of each line (`s/^/    /` assuming your editor is vi), and edit it into your post.

Comment: first, the compiler is C++11. I did what's recommended in the answer , the error is : error: passing ‘const timer’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool timer::is_time_out(double)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 return to.obj_timer.is_time_out(sec);

Comment: ok, i'll post the output, i just need to edit it, am unable to disclose some output information

Comment: @SamGomari: That's when you create a self contained, minimal test case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### First things first:

Let's note that this has very little to do with the lambda. The following code will also fail to compile:

```
sobj strobj;
is_stime(strobj.timer, 5);
```

#### Steps taken:

1. Let's reduce your test case down..
2. `is_stime()` needs to take a const reference, or your lambda needs to pass a non-const reference.
3. `is_stime()` is not visible to your lambda. [Would you like to know more?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593032/calling-friend-function-defined-in-struct-requires-forward-declaration)

#### Reduced Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int THE_ID;

class tmr {
};

struct sobj {
    int ID;
    tmr timer;

    friend bool is_stime(tmr const & objtimer, double sec);
};

bool is_stime(tmr const & objtimer, double sec) {
    return true;
}

int main() {
    vector<sobj> vecobj;
    vecobj.erase(std::remove_if(vecobj.begin(),vecobj.end(),[&](const sobj& mysobj){return ( mysobj.ID == THE_ID && is_stime(mysobj.timer,5));}),vecobj.end());
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to render "is_time_out(double sec)" of tmr class accessible/visible to lambda function, i can bypass struct's friend function

Comment: @SamGomari: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: you can see that tmr class has a function "is_time_out" , and since tmr object is a member of the sobj struct , i was wondering if one can simply have the lambda return the result of the "is_time_out" , without sobj having to have a function. Just directly access member function of tmr and return its result from lambda function to remove it from vector.

Comment: @SamGomari: I don't see any reason why you couldn't do that.

Comment: The issue was the const  in [&](const sobj& mysobj){return ... } . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

your lambda is missing a return type:

```
[&](const sobj& mysobj)->bool
```

Comment: Shouldn't this take care of it: [_if the body consists of nothing but a single return statement with an expression, the return type is the type of the returned expression (after rvalue-to-lvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer implicit conversion)_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: not sure the missing return is the issue, seems that even the single-return statement was relaxed, see e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955478/when-can-we-omit-the-return-type-in-a-c11-lambda

Comment: I do not think the return type is the issue.