# namespace in debug flags of in-class defined friend functions

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup, friend-function

I'm dealing with a class that defines a friend function in the class without outside declaration

```
namespace our_namespace {
template <typename T>
struct our_container {

  friend our_container set_union(our_container const &, our_container const &) {
    // meaningless for the example here, just a valid definition
    // no valid semantics
    return our_container{};
  }
};
}  // namespace our_namespace
```

As discussed (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785886/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593032)) the function `set_union` is not in the `our_namespace` namespace but will be found by argument dependent lookup:

```
auto foo(std::vector<our_namespace::our_container<float>> in) {
  // works:
  return set_union(in[0], in[1]);
}
```

I noticed however that [in the debug flags](https://godbolt.org/z/HbJemG) `set_union` appears to be in the `our_namespace` namespace

```
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 40] # 8-byte Reload
        mov     rsi, rax
        call    our_namespace::set_union(our_namespace::our_container<float> const&, our_namespace::our_container<float> const&)
        add     rsp, 48
        pop     rbp
        ret
our_namespace::set_union(our_namespace::our_container<float> const&, our_namespace::our_container<float> const&): # @our_namespace::set_union(our_namespace::our_container<float> const&, our_namespace::our_container<float> const&)
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 16], rdi
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 24], rsi
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

although I can't call it as `our_namespace::set_union`

```
auto foo(std::vector<our_namespace::our_container<float>> in) {
  // fails:
  return our_namespace::set_union(in[0], in[1]);
}
```

Any hints about how the debug information is to be understood?

EDIT: The `set_union` function body is only a strawdog example here to have a valid definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard only defines compiler behavior in regards to the code compilation and behavior of the resulting program. It doesn't define all the aspects of code generation, and in particular, it doesn't define debug symbols.

So your compiler correctly (as per Standard) disallows calling the function through namespace it is not in. But since the function does exist and you should be able to debug it, it needs to put debug symbol somewhere. Enclosing namespace seems to be a reasonable choice.

Comment: Hm, triggered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54580751), I looked at the intermediate compiler steps [here](https://godbolt.org/z/-ho6ka) and this looks like `set_union` is in the `our_namespace`. I'm confused.

Comment: @pseyfert do not confuse implementation detail with formal language rules. The rules are such that the name can't be found in the namespace (only through ADL lookup), so for all intents and purposes it is not in the namespace from the code point of view. The name exists, though, and compiler would need to generate the symbol and everything, and it puts the symbol in the namespace for codegeneration perspective.