# How can I use ADL in template deduction?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup, friend-function

I have a class with an in-class defined friend function that I would ideally not modify (it comes from a header that's already deployed)

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

namespace our_namespace {
template <typename T>
struct our_container {

  friend our_container set_union(our_container const &, our_container const &) {
    return our_container{};
  }
};
}  // namespace our_namespace
```

`set_union` is not declared outside the struct or namespace, but can normally be found through argument-dependent lookup (c.f. [Access friend function defined in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785886)). However, I ran into a situation where I need the function unevaluated (i.e. without arguments to be evaluated) for template type deduction. More specifically, I would like to use the friend function as a binary operation in `std::accumulate`:

```
auto foo(std::vector<our_namespace::our_container<float>> in) {      
  // what I really wanted to do:
  return std::accumulate(std::next(in.begin()), in.end(), *in.begin(),
                       set_union);
}
```

The only workaround I found so far is to wrap the function call into a lambda:

```
auto foo(std::vector<our_namespace::our_container<float>> in) {    
  // what I ended up doing:
  return std::accumulate(std::next(in.begin()), in.end(), in[0],
                       [](our_namespace::our_container<float> const& a, our_namespace::our_container<float> const& b) {return set_union(a,b);});
}
```

(and of cause I could define a function that does the same as  the lambda).

I've tried:

- specifying the namespace for `set_union` (what I usually do to get around ADL, but `set_union` isn't in a namespace)
- spell out template arguments to `set_union<our_container>` (but `set_union` lookup isn't failing at template argument deduction of `set_union`, and isn't templated itself)
- spell out the type of `set_union` with `…,decltype(set_union) set_union);` … except, here the lookup of `set_union` fails for the same reason, and providing arguments to `set_union` in the `decltype` would just trigger its evaluation and lead to the return type of `set_union` rather than its type.

Is there another way to use `accumulate` with ADL than this lambda?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer you are going to get is no.  That said, your lambda can be shortened to `[](auto const& a, auto const& b) {return set_union(a,b);}`

Comment: @NathanOliver wow. I wouldn't have thought that could work since the signature of the lambda is now unspecified when the template arguments needs to be deduced and that's before the lambda gets called to deduce it's argument types … but indeed you're right, it works (and the type of the lambda is fine with autos in it `foo(std::vector<our_namespace::our_container<float> >)::<lambda(const auto:1&, const auto:2&)>` )

Comment: It works because the type of the function is not deduced. a lambda expression generate an object that has an overloaded `operator()` (in this case it will be a template function).  It is the type of the object that gets deduced by `accumulate`, not the `operator()` call.  This is part of the reason functors/lambdas are so useful.

Comment: Actually you don't need the `const`s in the lambda either, `auto` will deduce `T const` instead of `T`: `[](auto &a, auto &b) {return set_union(a,b);}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a lambda looks like the best way to me.

As @NathanOliver suggested, you could shorten it to:

```
[](auto const& a, auto const& b) {return set_union(a,b);}
```

---

If you insist, there is an alternative, but it's somewhat ugly.

> specifying the namespace for set_union (what I usually do to get around ADL, but set_union isn't in a namespace)

It *is* in the namespace, but it can only be found with ADL.

If you redeclare it outside of the class, you'll be able to find it with the regular lookup:

```
namespace our_namespace
{
    our_container<float> set_union(our_container<float> const &, our_container<float> const &);
}

auto foo(std::vector<our_namespace::our_container<float>> in)
{
    // what I really wanted to do:
    return std::accumulate(std::next(in.begin()), in.end(), *in.begin(),
                           our_namespace::set_union<float>);
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't declare it as a template (since it's not a template).